# Overwrite an existing text file c++

Tags: c++, file, text, fstream, ofstream

This is how my Save As works - it is copying the current file's lines until it reaches the first figure and then I use my print methods to print the figure's info and then close the  tag.

```
std::ofstream newFile(filePath1_fixed, std::ios::app);
std::fstream openedFile(filePath);
std::string line1;
while (std::getline(openedFile, line1)) {
    if (line1.find("<rect") != std::string::npos
        || line1.find("<circle") != std::string::npos
        || line1.find("<line") != std::string::npos)
        break;
    newFile << line1 << std::endl;
}
figc.printToFile(newFile);
newFile << "</svg>\n";
```

My question is how to save the changes to the current file? I tried something like this:

```
std::ifstream openedFile(filePath);
std::ofstream newFile(filePath, std::ios::app);
std::string line1;
std::string info_beg[100];
int t = 0;
while (std::getline(openedFile, line1)) {
    std::cout << "HELLYEAH";
    if (line1.find("<rect") != std::string::npos
        || line1.find("<circle") != std::string::npos
        || line1.find("<line") != std::string::npos)
        break;
    info_beg[t++] = line1;
}
for (int i = 0; i < t; i++)
    newFile << info_beg[i] << std::endl;
figc.printToFile(newFile);
newFile << "</svg>\n";
```

This is the nearest I've gone. I get this:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="12cm" height="4cm" viewBox="0 0 1200 400"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <desc>Example rect01 - rectangle with sharp corners</desc>

  <!-- Show outline of canvas using 'rect' element -->
  <rect x="1" y="1" width="1198" height="398"
        fill="none" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2" />

  <line x1="20" y1="100" x2="100" y2="20"
        stroke="red" stroke-width="2" />

  <rect x="20" y="30" width="40" height="50"
        fill="red" stroke="red" stroke-width="1" />

  <rect x="10" y="20" width="30" height="40"
        fill="red" stroke="blue" stroke-width="1" />

  <line x1="100" y1="200" x2="300" y2="400"
        stroke="red" stroke-width="2" />

  <circle cx="10" cy="20" r="30"
        fill="red" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2" />

</svg>
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="12cm" height="4cm" viewBox="0 0 1200 400"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <desc>Example rect01 - rectangle with sharp corners</desc>

  <!-- Show outline of canvas using 'rect' element -->
  <rect x="1" y="1" width="1198" height="398"
        fill="none" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2" />

  <line x1="20" y1="100" x2="100" y2="20"
        stroke="red" stroke-width="2" />

  <rect x="20" y="30" width="40" height="50"
        fill="red" stroke="red" stroke-width="1" />

  <rect x="10" y="20" width="30" height="40"
        fill="red" stroke="blue" stroke-width="1" />

  <line x1="100" y1="200" x2="300" y2="400"
        stroke="red" stroke-width="2" />

  <circle cx="10" cy="20" r="30"
        fill="red" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2" />

  <rect x="10" y="20" width="30" height="40"
        fill="red" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2" />

</svg>
```

So my actual question is how to delete the first  or overwrite it or I need a different approach.

Comment: Define "save the changes to the current file". What does that mean?

Comment: a safer method is to write a new file (copying from the original if you like), then close them both, swap them, and delete the old one.
It's called 2-phase commit and it's been the way to safely modify files since computers were invented.

Comment: Using `ofstream` with the "current file" name as parameter for the constructor will overwrite it.

Comment: Can you explain why you chose to use `std::ios::app` if you instead want to overwrite the existing contents? What was the thought process that led to this decision?

Comment: @RichardHodges: "since computers were invented" is a bit of a reach ;)

Comment: I use std::ios::app because if I don't set it I lose the first lines from the file

Comment: @BoundaryImposition ok, since magnetic tape storage was invented in 1951 :)

Comment: @GeorgiGenchev: Okay, programming by guessing doesn't work. Clearly `std::ios::app` is going to be wrong, based on its definition. So that is not a solution. The solution is to not try reading from and writing to the same file at the same time!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use `ios::trunc` instead of `ios::app`

Using `std::ios::app` in the constructor for your `std::ofstream` tells the program to append to the file and not overwrite it. If you want to overwrite it (ie truncate), then using `std::ios::trunc` will tell the program to overwrite the existing file. `ofstream` does this by default, so you could just write the initialization as just `std::ofstream newFile(filePath);`.

Also, don't try to read the file and write to it at the same time; that won't work. Use `ifstream` to get the data into the buffer, then use `close()` to close the file. Then initialize newFile to overwrite the file and write out the buffer.

Comment: OP needs more than this, due to taking the to-write data from the same file at the same time.

Comment: Thank you, this helped. I managed to do it, just had to close the file from which I fill the buffer and then declare the ofstream.

Comment: As far as I understand, the default ofstream behaviour is to use std::ios::out which is not quite the same as trunc. out does not remove the original contents, but will start overwriting from the beginning. So one could end up in the situation of having a file containing new and old data, if the new stream is shorter than the old.